# FollowHyperlink in MS Access for websites that require a user password

Tags: ms-access

I want to add a 'Support' link to my MS Access form where users can click and access the support website. I tried the followHyperlink  but it didn't work with my website url.
I got this message: Runtime error "8":
The requested information cannot be downloaded. FollowHyperlink worked when I tried other websites. My Url comes from a private company website and each employee needs to be logged in to view the website. Could this be the reason and how can I solve it?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

If website requires username/password login, I doubt FollowHyperlink can accommodate. I will post my code that works with MS IE to open a website and pass username/password. AFAIK, MS Edge cannot be automated.

```
'open ASTM/AASHTO test standards website and pass agency username/password to web page
Dim oBrowser As InternetExplorer
Set oBrowser = New InternetExplorer
oBrowser.Silent = True
oBrowser.Navigate "https://login.ihserc.com/login/erc?"
oBrowser.Visible = True
Do
    'Wait till the Browser is loaded
Loop Until oBrowser.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
oBrowser.Document.all.Item("subAcctLoginName").Value = "username here"
oBrowser.Document.all.Item("subAcctPassword").Value = "password here"
oBrowser.Document.all.Item("Submit").Click
```